# Bowling: Middle finger pain hooking a house ball

Tags: bowling

I'm waiting on my first reactive ball to arrive, and in the meantime, I've been trying to hook a house ball.

I can hook the ball easily (if not accurately) thumb out, but when I put my thumb in, I tend to torque out my middle finger. It feels very unnatural, and I feel the technique should ideally be rather smooth. I could be wrong but the pain suggests a lateral force which is being applied to my finger as I try to rotate my hand out from my body and around the ball.

Is this because my fingers are too deep into the holes? I plan to get a fingertip pattern when my ball is drilled, but I'm hoping for some tips to improve my thumb-in efforts while I wait.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this. A house ball is not drilled to your hand so anything could be the case. I'd guess the span is too short and/or the finger hole is too wide. But it's a house ball, not too many optios here.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje. Yep. Got ball drilled. No more issue.